# How to use emailjs without UI just as a async function in Nextjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, email, next.js, nodemailer

```
import emailjs from "@emailjs/browser";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
export default async function sendEmail() {
    console.log("Inside the sendMail");

    // Replace these with your actual EmailJS Service ID, Template ID, and Public Key
    const serviceId = process.env.EMAILJS_SERVICE_ID;
    const templateId = process.env.EMAILJS_TEMPLATE_ID;
    const publicKey = process.env.EMAILJS_PUBLIC_KEY;
    console.log("hello");
    let formElement: JSX.Element = (
        <form>
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="user_name" value={"krishnaacharya"} />
            <label>Email</label>
            <input
                type="email"
                name="user_email"
                value={"krishna16acharya@gmail.com"}
            />
            <label>Message</label>
            <textarea name="message" />
            <input type="submit" value="Hello there" />
        </form>
    );
    // Create a temporary container element to render the JSX element
    const container = document.createElement("div");
    ReactDOM.render(formElement, container);

    // Retrieve the HTMLFormElement from the container
    const htmlFormElement = container.querySelector("form") as HTMLFormElement;

    try {
        const result = await emailjs.sendForm(
            serviceId!,
            templateId!,
            htmlFormElement, // ❗ this is of type HTMLFormElement here I am stuck I am not creating proper form element 
            publicKey
        );
        console.log(result.text);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Here is the error");
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

Presently this is the code I am trying and I am trying to call it in `api/sample`

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";
import sendEmail from "@/utils/email/emailNotify";

export async function GET(request: NextRequest) {


    try {
        await sendEmail();
        return NextResponse.json({ message: "OK" }, { status: 200 });
    } catch (error) {
        return NextResponse.json({ message: "Error", error }, { status: 500 });
    }
}
```

It is just giving internal error , no luck in forming the `htmlFormElement`

**Actually I am trying to convert the reactjs to nextjs :|**

https://www.emailjs.com/docs/examples/reactjs/

Sample of react given in the above link

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import emailjs from '@emailjs/browser';

export const ContactUs = () => {
  const form = useRef();

  const sendEmail = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    emailjs.sendForm('YOUR_SERVICE_ID', 'YOUR_TEMPLATE_ID', form.current, 'YOUR_PUBLIC_KEY')
      .then((result) => {
          console.log(result.text);
      }, (error) => {
          console.log(error.text);
      });
  };

  return (
    <form ref={form} onSubmit={sendEmail}>
      <label>Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="user_name" />
      <label>Email</label>
      <input type="email" name="user_email" />
      <label>Message</label>
      <textarea name="message" />
      <input type="submit" value="Send" />
    </form>
  );
};
```

**There is no example for nextjs**

Help me please !!

Comment: Your code looks ok. Any error in console?

Comment: Nothing there Mr @BadPiggie